# Quelles notions sémantiques sous-tendent « le fer » avec « clore » ?

Tags: étymologie

e ne pige pas [cette 3e étymologie](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fermer#Fran%C3%A7ais) pour *fermer*:

> [3.] D’autres enfin
>   attribuent au rattachement à *[fer](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fer)* par étymologie populaire le glissement de sens de « rendre
>   ferme » à « fermer » et donc l’éviction de *clore* par *fermer*, mais
>   elle est peu
>   vraisemblable <sup>[[1]](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fermer#reference-1)</sup>
>   et le sentiment linguistique auquel elle fait appel serait aujourd’hui
>   perdu.

Comment [*fer*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fer#Nom_commun_1) a-t-il glissé sémantiquement à signifier *clore* ?
Remarquez que la 3e étymologie compte sur rien des trois autres étymologies. Ainsi, n'y puisez pas SVP !

Comment: Du coup, quelle est la question que vous posez ?

Comment: Il faut se méfier des définitions issues de Wikipédia et encore plus lorsqu'il est ecrit : "D’autres enfin attribuent au rattachement à fer par étymologie populaire [...], **mais elle est peu vraisemblable** [...]"

Comment: @RémiHenry Clair maintenant ?